# Hibernate creates my tables automatically. Is there something wrong with that?

Tags: hibernate

First of all, I should say I'm a beginner with the Hibernate technology. (Well, In reality, I've used it in a few projects). But I want to know your opinion about this. 
I use Hibernate annotations to create all tables of my database in this way:

- Using "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop", (over and over again) Until I finally get the database model that I need.
- Then I try get the SQL Script from the database model generated by Hibernate (Using Workbench, by example).
- I drop my database, and then I create it again, but now using the SQL Script.
- After that, in my project, I change the property "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop" to "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update".

I want to know, am I using Hibernate in a right way? Or is it always recommended to create your database model first before anything else. (Or it depends on what kind of project are you working on)

Sorry for my spelling mistakes, if there are any.

Comment: I always do model-first (good SQL UI, 3rd party) and then use a schema-diff tool (3rd party) to generate update SQL scripts that are then deployed automatically (*only forward changes!*). I find this works really well and have had no problem doing continious-updates to deployed applications. I also use a different ORM (LINQ2SQL) and use a 3rd-party tool for updating model from the DB. I only hope there are similar solutions for hibernate. IMOHO: *model first*; it's less cool, but it works .. and it works predictably :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is acceptable, this is how you typically prototype and start with new project. However once you stabilize, you should take a little bit more action. First of all examine the script generated by Hibernate. Customize foreign key names, constraints, data types, etc. They are not always perfect.

Moreover watch out with `update` strategy. It's not always correct. In real world, once you you roll out first version of your application, you'll need more stable tools like [flyway](/questions/tagged/flyway) to manage database migrations.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is ok in a dev environment but you obviously cannot drop tables in production.

We had a similar issue earlier where we used to let hibernate create tables locally but use SQL ddl scripts on qa and staging. We ran into issues coz of inconsistency in data types.

So you have to be sure that the data types etc always match.

I guess the best practice is to mirror exactly what you do in prod on dev and use same SQL scripts to create tables.